# Autodetect console output encoding in perl

Tags: perl, encoding, console

I have a perl script that prints some information to console in Russian. Script will be executed on several OSes, so console encoding can be cp866, koi8-r, utf-8, or some other. Is there a portable way to detect console encoding so I can setup STDOUT accordingly so the text is printed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, there's [Win32::Codepage](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Codepage/).

Comment: The script will be run on any OS

Comment: On a Windows console, this is the best solution I know of. I don't know of a way of detecting the output encoding on Linux or other Unix-like systems. I usually set the terminal to UTF-8 encoding and use that for Perl. On Windows, as far as I know it is not possible to set the codepage of the terminal window. As for a portable solution, that would be great but I don't know if it exists.

Comment: On windows console encoding is set with `chcp` program, I suppose there is a programmatic solution also. Anyway, forcing some particular console encoding is not a solution.

Comment: This doesn't force an encoding, it detects the encoding. I don't know of a way to even change the encoding in the Windows console.

Comment: `chcp /?` output: "Displays or sets the active code page number."

Comment: And it can't "detect" anything by design: encoding is directly specified by caller.

Answer (score 2):

[`use open ':locale';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows. At least I failed to make it work. I believe it relies on environment variables to detect console encoding which usually are not set on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

- [Term::Detect::Software](http://p3rl.org/Term::Detect::Software)
- [Term::Encoding](http://p3rl.org/Term::Encoding)

Comment: That's interesting: `Term::Encoding::get_encoding()` returns `utf-8` on my Windows Server 2012 using cygwin perl. `chcp` shows that console is actually in `cp-437`, but perl scripts are able to print non-latin characters fine. So I am confused now.

Comment: Find out why the output of the `chcp` command and the [GetConsoleOutputCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683169(v=vs.85).aspx) API call disagree. Try with a native Perl instead of Cygwin.